# Obtaining form from an external JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'd like to access a form from an external JS file. My problem is that while I can access it for a single form using

```
document.forms[0]
```

and

```
$('form:eq(0)')
```

Given the scenario that there are multiple forms, I'd like to select the form that the user is currently using. (maybe select a form by its URL or something)

I want a generalized answer meaning that I already know how to access a form by its ID, class or attribute. Answers in jQuery and JavaScript are welcome. 
I'm kinda new to JS and JQ, a li'l help would be appreciated.

Say I'm using jQuery validation plugin,
 I do

```
$('form:eq(0)').validate()
```

*What I actually want to do*

is not to access form specifically, rather find out dynamically which form the user is accessing currently out of say 5 forms and assign that form value to the validate()

```
$('current form accessed by user').validate()
```

PROBLEM: I don't know how to access the current form value dynamically!

Comment: It would be great if you could provide more code that you have written in an attempt to solve this so we can help

Comment: Put yourself in our shoes. You give us 4 words of code. We don't even know what "external" js file means ("external" to what? To another js file? To the HTML document as it should be?) We have no code sample, no variable, no context, and you _want_ a general answer, for like all cases in the universe. Come on.

Comment: Okay, I am sorry, have edited the question with the code! External means it's just another JS file, nothing peculiar as you think!

Comment: you'd need to trigger your code on an event to check the form being used, such as a focus event `$('input').on('focus', function () { var form = $(this).parent().validate(); ` etc

Comment: Ty, I'll give a try, Is it possible to obtain the current form value via its URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`document.activeElement`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_document_activeelement.asp) to get the element that currently has focus, and then go up the chain with `parentNode`, until you either reach a `form` element (check against `.tagName`), in which case you found the form you're looking for, or until you reach the `html` element, in which case the user does not currently have a form selected.

One possible implementation using a `while(true)` loop:

```
function getSelectedForm()
{
    var el = document.activeElement;
    while(true)
    {
        if(el.tagName == 'HTML')
        {
            return null;
        }
        else if(el.tagName == 'FORM')
        {
            return el;
        }
        else
        {
            el = el.parentNode;
        }
    }
}
```

You might have to call the function as `$(getSelectedForm())` in order to be able to call `.validate()` on it.